# How to add a scroll view to an entire activity?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity, android-scrollview

I tried adding a scroll view around everything on an activity layout but it gave me an error saying it can only be placed around one thing.

My activity, has a title textview then an image, then a description text view, and you can not read the whole description because its to long and goes below the edge of my screen. How can I make the whoel thing scrollable?

My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDEscriptionTitle"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"

        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just add your parent linearlayout inside scroll view\

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- TextView and other stuff -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the `LinearLayout` (height is `wrap_content`) with `SrollView` (height is `fill_parent`).

Answer (score 0):

The "one thing" is your `LinearLayout`. Just wrap that in a `ScrollView` and you will encapsulate the layout for the entire activity.

Additionally, if you want to wrap just one elemtnet in a `ScrollView` all you have to do is put that element in it's own layout, like a linear or relative layout, and then that becomes the one element of your `ScrollView`

Answer (score 0):

just use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerTitle"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="40sp"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        >
    </TextView>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="10dip"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBrewery"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDEscriptionTitle"
        android:textStyle = "bold"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="Description"
        ></TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/beerDescription"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textSize="15sp"

        ></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: at the linear layout line I am getting this error:

Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Element type "ScrollView" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" 
  or "/>".
 - error: Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

Comment: It's missing the >, you need to make it
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">, also the end there should be </ScrollView> not <ScrollView/>.

Finally, with scrollviews, you may want to add the attribute android:fill_viewport="true" so your scrollview covers the whole screen.

Comment: yes that  was missed at edited time but it should work fine now :)